# Run 1 query instead of 14 based on DATE() in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's what I'm currently doing which I assume is using unnecessary resources on my server :

```
public function getDailyAverage($days) {
    global $db;
    $db->connect();
    $sql = $db->myRawQuery("
    SELECT 
        sum(`amount`) AS `total_earnings` 
    FROM 
        `earnings` 
    WHERE 
        `user_id` = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'
    AND
        DATE(`date`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ".$days." DAY))
    ");
    $db->disconnect();
    return (isset($sql[0]['total_earnings']) ? number_format($sql[0]['total_earnings'],2) : number_format(0,2));
}

public function getGraphData() {
    $day = 14;
    $data = array();
    do {
        array_push($data, $this->getDailyAverage($day));
        --$day;
    } while ($day > 0);
    return (count($data) > 0 ? implode(', ', $data) : array());
}
```

Obviously I'm making a single call on `$class->getGraphData()` but it's then running the same query 14 times just with a different day interval, is there any solution in mySQL that means I could do this just 1 time returning all results?

**UPDATE**

Here's a query I've tried which returns an error

```
SELECT
    SUM(`amount`) AS `total_earnings`, DATE_SUB(`date`, CUR_DATE()) AS `interval`
FROM 
    `earnings` 
WHERE 
    `user_id` = '66'
AND
    `date` >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
```

And the error that I'm being thrown is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CUR_DATE()) AS interval FROM `earnings` WHERE `user_id` = '66' ' at line 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with, I created another table called `calendar` with a single column named `datefield` I prefilled this with all dates within the past year.

I then changed my query to the following :

```
SELECT 
    calendar.datefield AS DATE, SUM(earnings.amount) AS total_earnings
FROM 
    earnings 
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendar ON (DATE(earnings.date) = calendar.datefield) 
WHERE 
    earnings.date >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)
GROUP BY
    DATE(earnings.date)
```

After changing my query, I changed my `getGraphData()` function to the following :

```
global $db;
$db->connect();
$data = array();
$sql = $db->myRawQuery("
SELECT 
    calendar.datefield AS DATE, SUM(earnings.amount) AS total_earnings
FROM 
    earnings 
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendar ON (DATE(earnings.date) = calendar.datefield) 
WHERE 
    earnings.date >= (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY)
GROUP BY
    DATE(earnings.date)
");
$db->disconnect();
foreach($sql as $row) {
    $a = new \DateTime($row['DATE']);
    $b = new \DateTime;
    $data[$a->diff($b)->days] = $row['total_earnings'];
}
$day = 0;
do {
    if(!array_key_exists($day, $data)) {
        $data[$day] = 0;
    }
    $day++;
} while($day < 14);
ksort($data);
return $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the interval as part of your field list:

```
SELECT ..., DATE_SUB(`date`, CUR_DATE()) AS interval
...
WHERE `date` >= CUR_DATE() - INTERVAL 14 days
```

That'll still give you your 14 days' worth of records, and a new field that says which day the record belongs to. Then your fetch code can do something simple like:

```
while ($row = fech_db_row($result)) {
   $data[$row['interval']][] = $row;
}
```

so you get a nice array keyed by how "old" the record is.

Comment: did you forgot about `GROUP BY` statement? `GROUP BY DATE_SUB(`date`, CUR_DATE())`

Comment: This query doesn't seem to work for some reason, I'll update my question with the query I tried